# How to solve "The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above."

Tags: firebase, android-studio, flutter

I'm still learning Firebase and Flutter. When I trying to connect a firebase first time an error comes up. I installed it step by step as in the Firebase website. But in Android Studio, the red color underline is showing the wrong thing. How can I fix this?

In this file, he shows the error. This is a file that was edited when installing Firebase
`Project/app/build.gradle`

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "kasun.com.flutterbookmanger"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex.1.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

See this screen shot [image]

This is the other file that was edited. `Project/build.gradle` file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Error code [image]
How to solve this? Please help.

Comment: from your error could not find com.android.support.multiex.1.0.3` try using androidX multidex `implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0` also see how to enable multidex https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: @griffins I changed. But the problem wasn't solved

Comment: Try flutter clean /delete build folder ten run again

Comment: @griffins how to clean

Comment: delete the build folder in your project or from your project folder on your terminal or cmd type 'flutter clean'.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update gradle version and should work fine

in Proect/build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
    ...
    ...
```

then you must update it in YOUR_APPLICATION_FOLDER/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

this helped me with same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
 if (flutterRoot == null) {
 throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with 
 flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
 }
```

I had this issue and it had nothing to do with firebase.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by closed the app from emulator (memory) . and start it from the first,i hope that can help you too.

Answer (score 0):

The magical command line "flutter clean" did the job for me

Answer (score 0):

Include this line as the first line in your file android/settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
```

Like this image:

[image]